# Plot attribute of shapefile with R

Tags: shapefile, r, fields-attributes, maps

Does anybody know how to plot any attribute of a shapefile with R?

For example, like this.

[image]

Comment: I would use ggplot2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28963405/1446289

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for an interactive graphical view, **mapview** is the right choice. Use

```
## load packages
library(raster)
library(mapview)

## download data
esp <- getData(country = "COL", level = 1)

## interactive plot
mapview(esp)
```

to display clickable polygons with a popup window showing you all the attribute values associated with a particular polygon. The package also features a version of `spplot` to display maps created via `mapview` statically (note that the function is still under heavy development).

```
## static plot
m <- mapview(esp)

spplot(m, zcol = "NAME_1", zoom = 6, 
       colorkey = FALSE, scales = list(draw = TRUE))
```